# tonumber and regex

Tags: regex, lua, numbers, lua-patterns

Given is a (time-value) String like:

```
local dt = "12:34:56"
```

I want to cut this string into

```
hh, mm, ss = "12", "34", "56"
```

therefore I use regex like this:

```
local hh = string.format("%02d", tonumber( dt:gsub(":..:..","") ))
local mm = string.format("%02d", tonumber( dt:gsub(":..:",""):gsub(":","") ))
local ss = string.format("%02d", tonumber( dt:gsub("..:..:","") ))
```

which works fine.
( The time string is coming from userinput, so I fill it with 0 if user writes "1" instead of "01")

But in cases where the value starts with 0, it is getting out of range for luas tonumber() (Signed zero I guess), same with "1", tonumber() seems to not handle values below "2")
Could anyone tell me how to handle this situation?

Beside this, I would be happy if you could show me the bad practice in my regex, if there's some.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole thing can be shortened to this one liner:

```
local hh, mm, ss = dt:match "(%d%d?):(%d%d?):(%d%d?)"
```

As for the error occuring in your `tonumber`, it is because `gsub` returns 2 values after its operation. First being the substituted sring and the second being a number. [`tonumber`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-tonumber) assumes the second argument to be the base provided (which would be 1 I think). Since numbers with base 1 can only be `0`; it raises an error.